# is it possible to add two values for the mouseOver command?

Tags: javascript, html

i want two things to happen when i move the mouse over an image, is there a way to write the code that way?

```
<a href="http://google.com/" target="_new"
  onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('301','','/w/w-1.gif',1)"
  onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
```

this is the original code for general rollover images in dreamweaver, but i want to add more to `onMouseOut=` and `Over=` like `onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()";"some command"` or how can i write this? im using javascript

i appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

The onMouse* properties usage is deprecated in modern browsers.
You should use addEventListener or something corresponding instead.
These 'listeners'-based implementations allow to add as much event-handlers as you want to any event.

I don't remember exact cross-browser syntax for this, but you can see it inside the the source code of any popular JS framework (like jQuery or Prototype or MooTools), or just use this framework.

Ofcourse it's possible to do something like:
`onMouseOver="func1();func2();func3();"`
But it's a bad-practice because this approach is incompatible with much of third-party JavaScript libraries you probably will use.

Answer (score 0):

Have it call a function that calls both functions.

**EDIT** It's even easier. Just do

```
onMouseOver="func1(); func2()"
```

Comment: how do i do that? can u give me a little example pls?

Comment: Or call several from the same attribute: `onmouseout="thingone(); thingtwo(); thingred(); thingblue();"`

Comment: @cdhowie - +1 - I like the way you made those functions rhyme.

Comment: what do i write between the (), like this? func1("MM_swapImgRestore()); ..."?

Comment: @alex, just like your example but remove the `"` quote around the `;`. `onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore();some command;some other command"`

Comment: No, I meant you'd do onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore(); some_command()" . You were almost there, just put all components inside the quotes - not literally func1, that was a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea of *Vadim*, you can do this:

```
// Others (Chrome, Firefox, etc)
document.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){thingone(); thingtwo();},false);
// IE
document.attachEvent("onmouseover",function(){thingone(); thingtwo();});
```

PS: Shall I quote *cdhowie* too, for the function names?